# How do I find the range of integers in a text file with python

Tags: python, range, text-files

after finding the average of values in my text file, I am wondering how I would find the range of the same values in the same text file.

What I have now:

```
file = open('stats.txt', 'a+')
file.write('\n' + 'Score: ' +str(score))
file.close()

with open('stats.txt') as fh:
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    for line in fh:
        count += 1 
        sum += float(line.split()[1])
    average = sum / count

#add range here

file = open('maths.txt', 'w+')
file.write('Average: ' + str(average))
file.close()
```

The text file stats.txt looks like this:

```
Score: 3
Score: 0
Score: 13
Score: 13
Score: 9
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 31
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: 0
Score: -8
Score: 0
Score: 0
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: what do you mean by range - minimum maximum? standard deviation?

Comment: Append your `float(line.split()[1]` values to a list and then use `max` and `min`? Alternatively, you could sort your file using a command-line tool and then grab the first and last values.

Comment: *"after finding the range of values in my text file, I am wondering how I would find the range of the same values in the same text file"* I'm not sure what this means.  Do the same thing again?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
file = open('stats.txt', 'a+')
file.write('\n' + 'Score: ' + str(1))
file.close()

numbers = []
with open('stats.txt') as fh:
    count = 0
    for line in fh:
        count += 1
        numbers.append(float(line.split()[1]))

file = open('maths.txt', 'w+')
file.write('Average: ' + str(sum(numbers)/len(numbers)) + "\n")
file.write('Max: ' + str(max(numbers)) + "\n")
file.write('Min: ' + str(min(numbers)) + "\n")
file.close()
```